# Multiple search terms and opening multiple files together?

Tags: windows-7, windows, search

Can anyone think of a way to do multiple file searches for files in a specific folder/sub-folder path, but have the results all kept on a single list?

I'd like this so that once the files have been located, I can open them all in one application (ie. Solidworks Assembly).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [FileSeek](http://www.fileseek.ca) (disclosure, I work for this company doing support and testing). FileSeek lets you specify multiple paths to search, and multiple criteria. For example, you could put C:\folder1|C:\folder2 in the Paths box, and then *filesearchtext1*|*filesearchtext2* in the Include Files box. All of the results will show up in the pane at the bottom, and then you highlight them, right-click, and choose Open.

Comment: Another application that should work is *Agent Ransack*, free at https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack. You can specify multiple paths to search, RegEx etc.